# Is "I cannot see obviously" right?

Tags: sentence-construction

I like to say I cannot see thing sharp because my eyes are weak and I dont have my glasses on. How should I put it? Can I say "I cannot see obviously." or " I see in a blur way".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"I cannot see clearly" is the usual way to indicate that your eyes are unable to focus properly.

"Obviously" means "there can be no other logical conclusion," and is the wrong word to use here. Sometimes "clearly" and "obviously" appear to be used interchangeably, because seeing is used as a metaphor for insight. However, the metaphor doesn't apply in the other direction.

Comment: Very informative!thx:) What if I cannot see the object because of obstacles between my eyes and the object, say due to haze or air pollution. May I say for example "I cannot see the mountains clearly due to the air pollution"?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot see obviously.

This sentence doesn't bring out the fact that you have a weak vision. The usage of obviously doesn't sit well here, and doesn't imply the desired meaning.

The simplest word to use would be "clearly":

> I cannot see *clearly*.

In sentences like these, clearly is very often used to describe a vision problem, as is indicated by several articles available online, like this one [here](https://mysolohealthstation.com/articles/view/cant-see-clearly-get-your-eyes-checked/):

> ***Can't See Clearly? Get Your Eyes Checked***
>
> *By CDC Published: June 4, 2012*
>
> To make sure you keep seeing clearly, get a comprehensive dilated eye
>   exam.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I might say one of the following:

> I can't see clearly without my glasses.
>
> I forgot my glasses so could you tell me what this says? (This is usually in a store where I can't read the receipt or the label on a shelf)